# Cryptictionary!

Tags: visual, cryptic-clues

After someone showed me "Cryptictionary" from the recent NPL con, I was inspired to make a puzzle, because I like drawing and I like cryptics :D

The rules are basically the same as cryptics, except using pictures. Pictures will contain a definition half, i.e. a drawing of the word, and a wordplay half

Anagrams could be indicated by objects in a blender, and insertions could be indicated by one object being literally in another, to give some examples

Also, your final answer should be in the form of a picture!

[image] B1 D6 C5 C1 B8 D4

[image] A1 C8 B5 A3 D5
[image] D3 B3 D1 A5

[image] C4 D8 A6 B4

[image] B7 A2 A8 D7 B6 C3

[image] D2 A7 B2 C7 C6

[image] C2 C9 A4

Comment: Wonderful puzzle!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The answers are

> HOLMES [spoken "homes"]
>  BATCH [half of batter + 1/7 of chocolate chips] 
>  FLOW [wolf reflected] 
>  DEAF [notes are D E A F] 
>  MADRID [top part of Riddler, who is angry] 
>  FRAME [double def, glasses frame and picture frame] 
>  INK [capless pink]

Using the alphanumerics gives:

> BACKWARD HALFTIME MIDDLEMAN OFFSHORE

which are additional wordplays, giving us

> back WARD -> DRAW
>  half of TIME -> ME 
>  middle of MAN -> A 
>  off (i.e. not right) SHORE -> HORSE

so:

> [image]

Comment: All correct.
Wow, I'm still not used to how crazy fast PSE is at solving stuff!

Comment: How do you go from `B1 D6 C5 C1 B8 D4` to `BACKWARD`? What did I miss?

Comment: @MorganG There are 4 words: A, B, C and D. The first letter of word A is A1 (the B of Batch), the second letter is A2 (A of Madrid) etc. Not that I would have worked it out without the answers in front of me, so +1

Comment: I would upvote this but there's no way that that is what you claim it to be!

Comment: @Strawberry how dare you...